# MySQL group data by hour to get average

Tags: php, mysql

```
....  
09.05.11 12:10 |    14,5  
09.05.11 12:00 |    19,5  
09.05.11 11:50 |    13,9  
09.05.11 11:40 |    15,4  
09.05.11 11:30 |    15,6  
09.05.11 11:20 |    14,3  
09.05.11 11:10 |    16,7  
09.05.11 11:00 |    19,3  
09.05.11 10:50 |    12,6  
09.05.11 10:40 |    10,8  
09.05.11 10:30 |    10,5  
09.05.11 10:20 |    15,6  
09.05.11 10:10 |    14,9  
09.05.11 09:00 |    10,1  
09.05.11 09:50 |    10,7  
....
```

I need `AVG` data for every hour.

ex. average data from `09.05.11 11.00` is calculated from  (`09.05.11 10.10` to `09.05.11 11.00`).

`12.00` from `11.10 - 12.00`  and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: Please can you include details of the `SELECT` query that you used to generate that data and the table structure too.

Comment: FYI it would be much easier to do grouping with 11:00 as `11:00-11:59` Would that work or do you have to do the grouping in the way that you described?

Comment: Grouping data 11:00-11:59 is easy and plain GROUP will do, but i need to group 11:10-12:00.
I cant alter input dates in any way.

Comment: Shouldn't you group by 11:10-12:09? Then it still would be easy : just group by time minus 10 minutes. Refer to the [DATE_SUB/DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) docs for more info.

Comment: I Just discovered that too :) damn its simple, why didnt i think that before. Thanks guys.

Comment: In this case `date - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE` makes everything right :)

Answer (score 5):

TRY

```
SELECT AVG( visit ) , HOUR( `time_column` ) 
FROM time_table
WHERE DATE_SUB(  `time_column` , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) 
GROUP BY HOUR( `time_column` )
```

#### working example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `time_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `waqt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `visit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `time_table`
--

INSERT INTO `time_table` (`id`, `waqt`, `visit`) VALUES
(1, '2011-07-28 13:29:04', 3),
(2, '2011-07-28 15:29:10', 4),
(3, '2011-07-28 13:45:35', 7),
(4, '2011-07-28 15:00:47', 5),
(5, '2011-07-28 14:45:03', 6),
(6, '2011-07-28 13:00:21', 3);
```

and then i execute per hour visit

```
  SELECT AVG(visit), HOUR(waqt) 
  FROM time_table    
  WHERE DATE_SUB(`waqt`,INTERVAL 1 HOUR) GROUP BY HOUR(waqt)
```